# TwitterKit.framework did not contain a “archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent” resource

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, testflight

I’m trying to archive my iOS swift application with TwitterKit integrated to put it on the TestFlight.

I’m getting the following error:
2017-11-08 09:20:30 +0000 [OPTIONAL] Didn’t find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 “Item at “/Users/shlomid/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-11-08/Mayu 08-11-2017, 11.20.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Mayu.app/Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework” did not contain a “archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent” resource.” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at “/Users/shlomid/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-11-08/Mayu 08-11-2017, 11.20.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Mayu.app/Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework” did not contain a “archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent” resource.}

What might be the problem and how to fix it? The TwitterKit is added to embedded binaries.

Comment: Hi, did you solve it?